# Process builder scheduled actions- operation rolled back error

Tags: workflow, process-builder, process

I have a simple Process builder with scheduled action which runs after **"0 hours after lastmodifieddate".**

It runs whenever **picklist A is changed on Account and updates picklist B on all related child Accounts** (Same object but with lookup self-relationship). Picklist A and picklist B have same values.

Now, whenever I change value in picklist A on parent Account; pending flow interview is created and child accounts get updated without any issues.
However when I do 2 updates in succession on the same field on parent account; it does not work. i.e. if I change field to value1 and save and then quickly change it to value2 and save. In this case two pending flow interviews are created as expected but updates won't happen. I receive an email with the following **error** message-

> "ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK: Record rolled back because not all
>   records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header."

As per other posts on Salesforce community, I checked my validation rules on Account; I manually updated child accounts and made sure that there is no issues.

Any help would be appreciated.